# Is a powerful two-way hash function provably impossible?

Tags: hash

A two-way hash function that could hash complex strings to a fixed length would change the world.

Imagine the decreased load on wires around the world if, for example, HTML pages could be hashed, then decoded by clients. Power (electricity) savings would be enormous.

Is it absolutely, without a shadow of a doubt, impossible to create a two-way hash function that can encode and decode long, complex strings? If there's even a slight chance that such a hash function could be developed, it seems it would be worth substantial investment of time and other resources to try to develop one.

Comment: It is impossible. And the proof is very simple, so simple in fact that you can verify it in your bedroom *right now* in a matter of seconds: take three pairs of socks. Distribute them among two drawers in any way you like. That's it. Try it. There is no way to distribute three pairs of socks among two drawers in such a way that there is at most one pair of socks in a drawer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it absolutely, without a shadow of a doubt, impossible to create a two-way hash function that can encode and decode long, complex strings?

It is absolutely, without a shadow of a doubt, impossible to create an encoding mechanism where you can transmit more than $2^s$ options in only $s$ bits.

Consider the decoding mechanism, which takes an encoding of $s$ bits, and generates the expanded output.  There are $2^s$ possible inputs (bit patterns), and hence there are (at most) $2^s$ possible outputs.

For a long, complex string, there are a huge number of such long, complex strings that we might want to send, and hence the $s$ you'll need is quite large.

Now, you can reduce the size somewhat; this is known as 'data compression', and it is fairly well studied technology.  However, such technology is dependent on the expected distribution of the preimage (it doesn't work on random data), and  the amounts of compression you get (assuming that the decompressor is required to return the exact same value that the compressor had, this is known as 'lossless compression') usually aren't that impressive for real inputs.

Comment: You can also mention the fact that a "perfect compression algorithm" cannot possibly exist for the same reason. If a perfect compression algorithm *were* to exist, then you could always improve it by applying the compression algorithm to its own output. And if you just do that often enough, it will compress any arbitrary input to nothing, which is clearly non-sensical. Ergo, a perfect compression algorithm cannot possibly exist.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: well, I'm not sure if that the 'iterated compressor' argument actually answers the question, as a compressor that couldn't get things smaller than (say) 1k would solve the OP's objective; the pigeon hole argument that I made would appear to me to be a better way of showing that isn't possible

Comment: A quick Fermi estimation tells me that there are less than 2^64 unique static resources on the web.